# I can not send message to telegram bot users but my self

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Why I can not send message to my bot users?

```
filename = 'a.png'

url = "https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyyyyy/sendPhoto";
files = {'photo': open(filename, 'rb')}

data = {'chat_id': "538087xx"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)

data = {'chat_id': "642201xx"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)

data = {'chat_id': "350225xx"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)
```

I'm trying to send message to 3 users, first one is me, the bot owner and I can receive the message. 2 other account already sent a message to the bot. but the results are:

```
(200, 'OK', '{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":77,"from":{"id":5258785xx,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"anal_bot","username":"rojandco_bot"},"chat":{"id":538087xx,"first_name":"Ehsan","username":"Shirzadi","type":"private"},"date":1542626038,"photo":[{"file_id":"AgADBAADeqwxG0-KmVNFxlFtWWBr7AQvuhoABG2shK_JcTywFuQEAAEC","file_size":1084,"width":90,"height":63},{"file_id":"AgADBAADeqwxG0-KmVNFxlFtWWBr7AQvuhoABKqN07Vwmbw_F-QEAAEC","file_size":12199,"width":320,"height":224},{"file_id":"AgADBAADeqwxG0-KmVNFxlFtWWBr7AQvuhoABCOVGKfhnnt_GeQEAAEC","file_size":49836,"width":800,"height":561},{"file_id":"AgADBAADeqwxG0-KmVNFxlFtWWBr7AQvuhoABAyOV-TH27bRGOQEAAEC","file_size":99617,"width":1280,"height":898}]}}')
(400, 'Bad Request', '{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: file must be non-empty"}')
(400, 'Bad Request', '{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: file must be non-empty"}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open the file on the fourth line with

```
files = {'photo': open(filename, 'rb')}
```

The first `request.post` call probably closes the file handle thereby not making it available to the second and the third `request.post`.

The error message that you posted has the information you need. To fix this, simply re-open the file before you post data every time.

Edit:
Wombatz is right `requests.post` reads to the end of the file.

Here's how you'd seek to the beginning of the file:

```
files['photo'].seek(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `requests.post` reads the file, but does not reset it to the starting position as can be seen [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/57d7284c1a245cf9fbcecb594f50471d86e879f7/requests/models.py#L110): In line `159` the reading happens.

So, your first `post` works, but all subsequent requests will send an *empty* file to telegram. That is actually the exact thing telegram is telling you with `"Bad Request: file must be non-empty"`: you are sending an empty file.

That means, in order to send the same file multiple times, you could either reopen the file or seek to the beginning of the file or - as you are reading the file anyways - pass the contents of the file directly to `requests` (probably the best solution of the three) like this:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as photo:
    files = {'photo': photo.read()}  # note that we actually read() the file here

for user in all_the_users_you_want_to_send_the_file_to:
    requests.post(url, files=files, ...)
```

Note that this works, because `requests` also accepts a string instead of a file-like object. Like this the file is read only once which might be faster depending on the file size. (see the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for more details)

Also note that you *really should* should use the `with` statement when reading or writing files.

`requests` does **not** close the file when it's done. In that case you would see an error message like

> ValueError: read of closed file